# Returning an ordered list of dependent nodes

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, graph, nodes

I am creating a program that asks for how many nodes there are, if any are dependent on another, and then outputs the final ordered list. For e.g. if there are 3 nodes `['a', 'b', 'c']` if `b` is dependent on `c`, then the final list is: `['a', 'c', 'b']` (as c will come before b).

I've looked up something called dependency injection however this is not completely clear to me and is confusing me further.

My code so far is:

```py
import string
alpha = string.ascii_lowercase          # Importing the alphabet to convert

def convert(x):                         # Converting the numeric value into alphabetic character
    for i in range(1, x):
        return list(alpha[0:x])

x = int(input("Enter how many nodes there are:  "))
print(convert(x))

new_list = []
```

Where I have asked the user how many nodes there are, and then outputs an alphabetical list.`new_list` is to be the final ordered list which is the part I'm stuck on.

I want to know how to do something like:

```
Which node is node 'a' dependent on?  (Input: None)
Which node is node 'b' dependent on?  (Input: c)
Which node is node 'c' dependent on?  (Input: None)

output: ['a', 'c', 'b']
```

If there is a node that is not linked to any other it doesn't matter what order it is in, so the output could also be `['c', 'a', 'b']` or `['c', 'b', 'a']`, as long as the 'parent' node is before the dependant node.

Edit: Circular dependencies are invalid. So if `a` was dependent on `c` and vice versa, there would be an error message.

Comment: It would help to give more context on the problem you are working on. For example your output will not allow you to infer dependency fully, given the output only you could assume 'a' is dependent on 'c' or 'b'.

Comment: What would happen if `a` is dependent on `c`, but `c` is also dependent on `a`?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh - The result would be an error as circular dependencies are not allowed.

Comment: @vekerdyb - not sure what you are asking? All the context needed is in the question. I understand my output doesn't conclude dependency...I'm asking how to go from there?

Comment: I'm wondering why do you try to get an ordered list, instead of some other data structure, such as a dict: {'a': None, 'b': None, 'c': ['b']} which is more expressive of a dependency relationship to me. That's what I mean by providing more context: what are the dependent "things"? What do you want to use the output for?

Comment: @vekerdyb - oh I get you. A dict is unnecessary for this question. The output is just to show which node comes first is all. So for that eg ['a', 'c', 'b'] it's just to show the order of say - completed tasks, or a travelled path way.

Comment: So would you also accept ['c', 'b', 'a'] as a valid path for example, but not ['b', 'c', 'a'] because 'c' depends on 'b'?

Comment: @vekerdyb - Yes that is correct. If there is a node that is not linked to any other it doesn't matter what order it is in

Comment: @TheWonderer Thanks, can you clarify this in your question? It will make it easier to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Preface:**
I see this as a graph theory / pathfinding problem. However almost everything can be represented as a graph theory problem -- for me this interpretation seems easiest, something else might work better for you.
Note that I broke down the task to several smaller steps: getting a simplistic "dependency graph", generate all possible paths, and validating each path until finding one that validates.

**Solution**

If the number of nodes is relatively small, you could try to generate all paths and then check each to see if one of them is valid or not.

I haven't extensively tested the code below, but something like this is a good start:

```
import itertools
import string


def get_nodes():
    alpha = string.ascii_lowercase  # Importing the alphabet to convert
    x = int(input("Enter how many nodes there are:  "))
    return list(alpha[0:x])


def get_dependency_graph(nodes):
    dependency_graph = {}

    for node in nodes:
        dependent_node = input(f"Which node is node {node} dependent on? (press Enter if none) ") or None
        dependency_graph[node] = dependent_node
    return dependency_graph


def generate_all_paths(nodes):
    return itertools.permutations(nodes)


def validate_path(path, dependency_graph):
    for i, node in enumerate(path):
        head = path[:i]
        dependency = dependency_graph[node]
        if not dependency:
            continue
        if dependency_graph[node] not in head:
            return False
    return True


def get_valid_path(nodes, dependency_graph):
    possible_paths = generate_all_paths(nodes)
    for path in possible_paths:
        if validate_path(path, dependency_graph):
            return path
    print("No path found :(")


def run():
    nodes = get_nodes()
    dependency_graph = get_dependency_graph(nodes)
    path = get_valid_path(nodes, dependency_graph)
    print(path)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

If you expect a large number of nodes, a more sophisticated way might be required (but judging by the way you try to convert to the letters of the alphabet, I assume you expect less than 26).

Comment: Wow thank you - I didn't realise it would be this long of a code. What should I look up to study this topic more?

Comment: @TheWonderer I edited my answer to include a preface